# Facebook: How do I retrieve all reviews I have ever posted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, review

I would like to be able to get all reviews that I have ever posted on Facebook. I have tried it via the Graph API Explorer with no success, in FQL Query:

```
SELECT review_id FROM review WHERE reviewer_id=me()
```

This returns an empty JSON object.

In Graph API `me/reviews`returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Is it possible at all or am I wasting my time?

Thanks